# Doctrine 2.2+ wants to recreate all my tables because it's attempting to use the wrong postgres schema

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I updated doctrine from 2.1 to 2.2 on a symfony 2.0 project.

But now every time I try to do `php app/console doctrine:schema:update` doctrine wants to recreate all my schema and I have the following error:

> Duplicate table: 7 ERREUR:  the relation account already exists.

When I dump the SQL, it is clearly recreating all the database.

Comment: Stupid question but have you cleared your projects cache?

Comment: Yes i cleared the cache.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When upgrading from 2.1 to 2.2, Doctrine now tries to specify the schema.

In doctrine 2.1: You can't specify the Schema, and Doctrine will create tables in the `public` schema

In doctrine 2.2+: If no schema is specified, Doctrine will write into the user schema and then in the public schema.

To specify the schema for the user that's performing the queries, just do:

```sql
alter user your_user set search_path = my_schema
```

Comment: This sounds like my problem. Where do I specify the schema?

Comment: I didnt' find where to specify the schema although i didn't really look. I changed the search path in postgres. and put public before the user schema

Comment: I ended up doing the same. It seems strange that this didn't affect the normal runtime operation. Maybe a bug or inconsistency in Doctrine or Symfony.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15280032/how-do-i-specify-which-schema-to-use-for-doctrine-2-2-symfony-2-2-and-postgres