# How do I specify which schema to use for Doctrine 2.2 / Symfony 2.2 and PostgreSQL?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the same problem as reported here: [Doctrine 2.2 wants to recreate all my tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178207/doctrine-2-2-wants-to-recreate-all-my-tables)

I'm using PostgreSQL and my tables are in the public schema.

app/console doctrine:schema:update wants to recreate all my tables, apparently because it's looking in the user schema, not public. My Symfony application works fine as it is which seems a little strange.

With Symfony 2.2 / Doctrine 2.2 where do I specify the schema?  I can't seem to find it in any documentation.

Answer (score 10):

If you're using the `public` schema, you don't have to do anything special, because PostgreSQL fallbacks to it automatically.

However, if you want to specify another schema — or enforce the usage of the `public` schema in case PostgreSQL fallbacks to another one for some reason — the `@Table` annotation has the [`schema` property](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/Table.php#L33-L36):

```php
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Table;

/**
 * @Table(schema="some_schema")
 */
class Entity 
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't really explain why app/console doctrine:schema:update tries to do things on the user schema, rather than public and how to stop it. I've just solved my immediate problem by editing my PostgreSQL config to take $user out of the search_path as explained here http://forums.enterprisedb.com/posts/list/302.page but ... I think I'm missing something in the bigger picture. I'm new to PostgrSQL

Comment: That's probably happening because you have a schema in the database named after your username and PostgreSQL tries to use it and only after that fallbacks to the `public` schema. Just drop that schema.

Comment: I only seem to have the public schema, at least that's all I can see in pgAdmin.

Comment: This is not working for table migrations and this is not excluding others schemas from doctrine management.

Answer (score 1):

For **symfony 5.4** use this in your entity file

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Table(name: "schema_name.table_name")]
class Entity
{
...
}
```

I don't know if it works for lastest versions

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. Doctrine utilizes the following query to retrieve database schema information:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.schemata
```

When the user lacks sufficient privileges or is not the owner of a schema, the query returns no results.

I resolved the issue by modifying the owner of the public schema to match the user used by Doctrine:

```
ALTER SCHEMA public OWNER TO my_user
```