# How to query a table in a schema in symfony2 via doctrine?

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

My database is postgreSQL. I've set my parameters as below:

```
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_pgsql
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: null
    database_name: sandbox
    database_user: postgres
    database_password: postgres
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    locale: en
    secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
```

The problem is that I don't know how to query the existing tables in `PostgreSQL`. I have no problem with `MySQL`, but in `PostgreSQL` I don't actually know what to do.

EDIT:

```
# app/config/parameters.yml
parameters:
database_driver: pdo_mysql
database_host: localhost
database_name: test_project
database_user: root
database_password: password
```

And then I create entities to work with my data.

**EDIT2:**

> ---
>
> Tables are already created in postgreSQL. The connection part is done. I've done it successfully. What I want to do now is to create entities based on existing tables. I think now it's much more clear and no one is on the dark side. ;-)

Comment: Can you show us an example of how you do it with MySQL?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15280032/how-do-i-specify-which-schema-to-use-for-doctrine-2-2-symfony-2-2-and-postgres

Comment: In your edit, why is `database_driver` set as `pdo_mysql`? Should it be `pdo_pgsql`?

Comment: @kix, read the question completely. Luke has asked for the MySQL way.

Answer (score 1):

The setup for Postgresql and MySQL are very similar.  You do need to make a change outside of the Symfony2 php files to be able to use Postgresql with PHP.  In the php.ini file, make sure you enable the extension for pgsql.  This needs to be enabled so you can use the database_driver pdo_pgsql

Php.ini file    /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini, add:

```
 extension=pdo.so
 extension=php_pdo_pgsql.so
```

After this, test that you can either connect to your existing database or create a new database.  use schema create or validate depending on your situation and post any errors you receive.

Comment: I can connect to Postgres, the problem is that I alreay have existing tables and I don't have any entity for them. I don't know how to query those tables

Comment: Ok, so you have tables in postgresql, but no entities related to these tables in your symphony project?  You will need entities and can use doctrine to help reverse engineer to create the entities, but this does not create the entities perfectly.  try:  $ php doctrine orm:convert-mapping --from-database yml /path/to/mapping-path-converted-to-yml as specified in the [doctrine docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/tools.html#reverse-engineering)

Comment: in symfony that would be `php app/console doctrine:orm:convert-mapping`

Comment: @George, I've tried that and it works just on my public schema. Is there a way to select your schema or set them? tnx

Comment: If you want to connect to tables in Postgresql from Symfony via doctrine, I think your schema will need to be public because you need to connect to it.  I never created a private schema so not sure how to change that.  You can try manually creating one entity from your postgresql database in symphony, and see if that can connect to your table correctly.  Reverse engineering may be best done manually if you are having problems since every field will need to be checked.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a couple of symfony applications using postgres although with doctrine dbal and not the orm. My parameters.yml is usually something like this:

```
database_driver: pdo_pgsql
database_host: localhost
database_port: 5432
database_name: my_db_name
database_user: my_user
database_password: my_password
```

Since you said you can connect to the database, create your entities for the tables like
this for example:

```
<?php
/*
 *@Entity
 *@Table(name="my_schema_name.my_table_name")
 */
class Message
{
   /** @Column(type="integer") */
   private $id;
   /** @Column(length=140) */
   private $text;
   /** @Column(type="datetime", name="posted_at") */
   private $postedAt;
}
```

Pay attention to the annotations on the table name. Specify both the schema and the table.
After that, try to query all the records in that table using dql.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you look at the EDIT2 part in the question/ thanks.