# doctrine:schema:update gives error "the relation abc already exists"

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I ran into an issue today, for which I'd like to share the solution:

`doctrine:schema:update` throws this error:

```
Duplicate table: 7 ERROR: the relation abc already exists.
```

In my case, this occurred after upgrading from PostgreSQL 9.4 to 9.5 and from Symfony 2.7 to 2.8.

After a while, I found out that it's somehow related to this issue:
[Doctrine 2.2 wants to recreate all my tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178207/doctrine-2-2-wants-to-recreate-all-my-tables)

Details:

- When running against an empty database, `doctrine:schema:update` works fine (i.e. creates everything).
- When running for the second time, I get the error above. So it looks like Doctrine can't *find* the already existing tables.
- And the really weird thing: The Symfony application works! I.e. Doctrine *does* find the tables in principle - just not when doing `schema:update`

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer - thanks to @tetranz: [How do I specify which schema to use for Doctrine 2.2 / Symfony 2.2 and PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15280032/how-do-i-specify-which-schema-to-use-for-doctrine-2-2-symfony-2-2-and-postgres#comment21559556_15280311):

1. In pgAdmin III, click `File` > `Open postgresql.conf` (this file is located where your database data is).
2. Look for a setting named `search_path` (it's rather at the top).
3. Activate this setting (i.e. click the checkmark) and modify its value from `"$user", public` to `public`

My guess:
When running "normally", Doctrine does find the table, since I did specify the schema in the configuration files (*.yml). But when looking for the tables with `schema:update`, Doctrine omits the schema, thereby falling back to PostgreSQL's default search path, which is `"$user"` (i.e. the user name of the current PostgreSQL user, normally `postgres`). So to me, this looks like a Doctrine bug.